# Remove duplicates and sum values in R

Tags: r, sum, duplicates

I have a dataset, df, that looks like this but has a few million instances:

`Date           AD     Runway    MTOW    nr.flights
2008-01-01     A       18        376      2
2008-01-01     A       18        376      2
2008-01-01     D       36        190      1
2008-01-02     D       09        150      2
2008-01-02     A       36        280      1
2008-01-02     A       36        280      1`

And I want it to look like this:

`Date          AD     Runway    MTOW    nr.flights
2008-01-01    A       18        752       4
2008-01-01    D       36        190       2
2008-01-02    D       9         150       2
2008-01-02    A       36        560       1`

Basically I want to group together all the Date, AD and Runway rows that are the same, so all the duplicates are removed. At the same time, I want the MTOW and nr.flights to be summed up for that particular Date, AD and Runway.

I've tried this:
`vals <- expand.grid(Date = unique(df$Date),
                    Runway = unique(df$Runway),
                    AD = unique(df$AD))`

So I could merge this with the original dataset, df, but that didn't work. I have also tried a few combinations of group_by but that also didn't give me the result that I wanted.

To reproduce:

```
df <- data.frame(Date=c("2008-01-01","2008-01-01","2008-01-01","2008-01-02","2008-01-02","2008-01-02"),
              AD = c("A", "A", "D", "D", "A", "A"), Runway = c(18, 18, 36, 09, 36,36), 
              MTOW = c(376, 376, 190, 150, 280, 280), nr.flights = c(2,2,1,2,1,1))
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one that uses the package *plyr*:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,~Date + AD + Runway,summarise,MTOW=sum(MTOW),nr.flights=sum(nr.flights))
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 5):

With library `dplyr`, you can do something like this:

```
df %>% group_by(Date, AD, Runway) %>% summarise(MTOW = sum(MTOW), nr.flights = sum(nr.flights))
Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
Groups: Date, AD [?]

        Date     AD Runway  MTOW nr.flights
      (fctr) (fctr)  (dbl) (dbl)      (dbl)
1 2008-01-01      A     18   752          4
2 2008-01-01      D     36   190          1
3 2008-01-02      A     36   560          2
4 2008-01-02      D      9   150          2
```

There are many such posts and examples already I think.

Comment: Thank you for answering! This solution worked on my example data set, but somehow it didn't work on my original dataset.. I don't know why yet. But I have the solution now though, so thanks anyway!

Comment: Best way to thank on stackoverflow is to up vote or accept answers. :)